# PLS 00103 error: Encountered the Symbol: IS, end-of -file

Tags: sql, function, oracle11g

The below query when executed is giving errors: PLS 00103. Can you please help me find out the erros here. I have tried other combinations like ELSIF, but all give errors.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
  FUNCTION fnExpirationDateCondition
    (
      ExpirDateStr  IN VARCHAR2,
      OptionDateStr IN VARCHAR2 ) // Error 1 here
    RETURN INTEGER ExpirDate DATE; // Error 2 here
    OptionDate TIMESTAMP;
  IS
  BEGIN
    ExpirDate   :=TO_DATE(ExpirDateStr,'YYYY-MM-DD');
    OptionDate  :=TO_TIMESTAMP(OptionDateStr, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF');
    IF(ExpirDate > OptionDate) THEN
      RETURN 1;
    ELSE
      IF(ExpirDate < OptionDate) THEN // Error 3 here
        RETURN -1;
      ELSE
        RETURN 0;
      END IF;
    END IF;
  END;
```

Errors:
1.) Encountered the symbol "ExpirDate" when expecting one of the following:
2.) Encountered the Symbol "IS" when expecting one of the following:
3.) Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

I have also tried replacing `ExpirDate   :=TO_DATE(ExpirDateStr,'YYYY-MM-DD')`   with   `TO_DATE(ExpirDateStr,'YYYY-MM-DD') INTO ExpirDate`. it doesn't seemed to work.

Any suggestions will be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you've got your variable declarations happening before the `IS` that marks the start of the function's declaration section.

Try this, instead:

```
create or replace function fnexpirationdatecondition
    (expirdatestr  in varchar2,
     optiondatestr in varchar2)
return integer 
is
  expirdate date;
  optiondate timestamp;
begin
  expirdate := to_date(expirdatestr,'YYYY-MM-DD');
  optiondate := to_timestamp(optiondatestr, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF');

  if(expirdate > optiondate) then
    return 1;
  elsif(expirdate < optiondate) then
    return -1;
  else
    return 0;
  end if;
end fnexpirationdatecondition;
/
```

Or, alternatively, you could just have a single return statement (recommended), and just use a case statement to handle the if-elsif-else logic:

```
create or replace function fnexpirationdatecondition
    (expirdatestr  in varchar2,
     optiondatestr in varchar2)
return integer 
is
  expirdate date;
  optiondate timestamp;
begin
  expirdate := to_date(expirdatestr,'YYYY-MM-DD');
  optiondate := to_timestamp(optiondatestr, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF');

  return case when (expirdate > optiondate) then 1
              when (expirdate < optiondate) then -1
              else 0
         end;
end fnexpirationdatecondition;
/
```

Comment: Thank You @Boneist. Worked perfectly